# Bash Profile Setting not working for path - PS1

Tags: bash, ps1

I've written the following bash profile settings file:

```
BLACK="\[\033[0;30m\]"
DARK_GRAY="\[\033[1;30m\]"
LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
LIGHT_BLUE="\[\033[1;34m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
LIGHT_GREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
LIGHT_CYAN="\[\033[1;36m\]"
RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
PURPLE="\[\033[0;35m\]"
LIGHT_PURPLE="\[\033[1;35m\]"
BROWN="\[\033[0;33m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[1;33m\]"
WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
DEFAULT_COLOR="\[\033[00m\]"


function prompt_command {
    # How many characters of the $PWD should be kept
    local pwd_length=23
    if [ $(echo -n $PWD | wc -c | tr -d " ") -gt $pwd_length ]
    then 
        newPWD="$(echo -n $PWD | sed -e "s/.*\(.\{$pwd_length\}\)/\1/")"
    else
        newPWD="$(echo -n $PWD)"
    fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command;

PS1="\`if [ \$? = 0 ];
then
    echo -e '$PURPLE[\t] $LIGHT_CYAN\u$YELLOW@\h$WHITE: $newPWD $GREEN$ $DEFAULT_COLOR';
else
    echo -e '$PURPLE[\t] $LIGHT_CYAN\u$YELLOW@\h$WHITE: $newPWD $RED$ $DEFAULT_COLOR';
fi; \`"
export PS1;
```

For some reason getting the newPWD is not working. It is present in the enviroment (I can print it with the echo), however it isn't added to the command lines prompt. There an empty string is added always. So a sample output is:

```
[11:54:09] ber@szak:  $
```

Any ideas why not?

---

PS. Here it is my solution to this:

```
BLACK="\[\033[0;30m\]"
DARK_GRAY="\[\033[1;30m\]"
LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
LIGHT_BLUE="\[\033[1;34m\]"
GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
LIGHT_GREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
LIGHT_CYAN="\[\033[1;36m\]"
RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
PURPLE="\[\033[0;35m\]"
LIGHT_PURPLE="\[\033[1;35m\]"
BROWN="\[\033[0;33m\]"
YELLOW="\[\033[1;33m\]"
WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
DEFAULT_COLOR="\[\033[00m\]"

export MYPATHPS='$(
    echo -n "${PWD/#$HOME/~}" | 
    awk -F "/" '"'"'{
        if (length() > 14) {
            if (NF>4) print  "/"  "/.../" $(NF-1) "/" $NF;
            else if (NF>3) print  "/"  "/.../" $NF;
            else print  "/.../" $NF;
        }
        else print ;
    }'"'"'
)';

PS1="$PURPLE[\t] $LIGHT_CYAN\u$YELLOW@\h \` if [ \$? = 0 ]
    then
        echo -en '$GREEN'
    else
        echo -en '$RED'
    fi;
\` $MYPATHPS $ $DEFAULT_COLOR ";
export PS1;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `export` newPWD. Just because you can `echo` it doesn't mean its in the environment. It means its set in the shell and/or the environment. To know if something is in the environment I would use:

```
env | grep '^newPWD'
```

I'm not sure but I don't think that using `newPWD` like this is going to work, as `newPWD` is not reset every time you change directory like `PWD` is. So you may end up needing to change your `PS1` setting to call the `prompt_command` function each time.

From your comments looks like my guess about `newPWD` was right. So what you need to do is change the `prompt_command` function to `echo` the prompt that you want. Then change your `PS1` setting to

```
PS1="\`if [ \$? = 0 ];
                then
                    echo -e '$PURPLE[\t] $LIGHT_CYAN\u$YELLOW@\h$WHITE: $(prompt_command) $GREEN $DEFAULT_COLOR';
                else
                    echo -e '$PURPLE[\t] $LIGHT_CYAN\u$YELLOW@\h$WHITE: $(prompt_command) $RED $DEFAULT_COLOR';
              fi; \`"
export PS1;
```

Note: I also removed the trailing `$` from `$RED$` and `$GREEN$` as I assumed they were typos. Not sure if that was right

Comment: Sure enough it wasn't exported. However, exportin both the COMMAND_PROMPT or/and the function itself still did not solved the problem. I would want somehow to set the PS1 so the newPWD will get updated (by the prompt_command function) every time I run a command.

Comment: Updated answer to show how to do this. Basically change `prompt_command` to output desired prompt instead of setting a variable. Then use `$(prompt_command)` in `PS1`

Comment: Well the $ there isn't the typo, it's there to show a $ at the end of the query. Aside from this you're right. In the meantime managed to figure it out. Actually it works as I posted, just need to move then $newPWD outside the ``quotes of the PS1.